# Android Sentry not showing logs in dashboard

Tags: android, sentry

I'm adding Sentry to my android wearable application to log crashes. However Sentry is not sending/showing any events in the dashboard.

I'm testing on an android emulator which has internet acces. I'm using the following setup:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_home);

    Sentry.init("http://public:private@sentry.io/app_id?async=false", new AndroidSentryClientFactory(this.getApplicationContext()));

    try{
        int i = 4 / 0;
    } catch (Throwable ex) {
        Sentry.capture(ex);
    }
}
```

AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
```

The only logs I am getting are:

> 03-04 18:58:54.214
>   31757-31757/nl.jamieknoef.homewizard.homewizard_java
>   D/io.sentry.android.AndroidSentryClientFactory: Construction of
>   Android Sentry.
>
> 03-04 18:58:54.226
>   31757-31757/nl.jamieknoef.homewizard.homewizard_java
>   D/io.sentry.android.AndroidSentryClientFactory: Sentry init with
>   ctx='nl.jamieknoef.homewizard.homewizard_java.HomeWizardApp@82709d8'
>   and dsn='Dsn{uri=http://sentry.io/}'
>
> 03-04 18:58:54.287
>   31757-31757/nl.jamieknoef.homewizard.homewizard_java
>   D/io.sentry.android.AndroidSentryClientFactory: Using buffer dir:
>   /data/user/0/nl.jamieknoef.homewizard.homewizard_java/cache/sentry-buffered-events
>
> 03-04 18:58:54.376
>   31757-31757/nl.jamieknoef.homewizard.homewizard_java
>   D/io.sentry.android.event.helper.AndroidEventBuilderHelper: Proguard
>   UUIDs file not found.

Any idea's what causing Sentry to not send events?

Comment: did you ever find a solution for this?

Comment: @Bohrend I did fix it. I am not entirely sure if this was the fix but.. I created a sentry.properties in src/main/resources and after a few minutes my logs were showing up. Also, I noticed Sentry doens't immediatly send logs, it only seems to send logs when you boot the application up. Sentry logs messages whenever it sends your exception to their servers. So if you crash your application on your first activity in the onCreate method like I did, it probably won't get the time to ever send your exceptions.

Answer (score 3):

I noticed Sentry doesn't immediatly send logs, it periodically sends your exceptions to their servers. So if you crash your application on your first activity in the onCreate method like I did, it probably won't get the time to ever send your exceptions.